# how to implement drag and drop in snap.svg for mobile devices

Tags: drag-and-drop, touch, snap.svg

How do I implement drag and drop for mobile devices in Snap.svg?  Touch drag and drop does not seem to be built into the Snap.svg drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Comment in wrong place, sorry -- moved below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an attempt to do a drag and drop that will work for either mouse or touch handlers.

It does a quick check on the first parameter to see if its a number (so a mouse drag ), or an object ( so a touchevent ).

It then takes the first element of the changedTouches list. I assume this should be sufficient, but maybe one would want to loop through the touches list if necessary.

The circle should work with either mouse or touch, the rect only with touch.

```
var s = Snap(400,400); 

var rect = s.rect(20,20,40,40);
var circle = s.circle(60,150,50);

var move = function(dx,dy,x,y) {
    var clientX, clientY;
    if( (typeof dx == 'object') && ( dx.type == 'touchmove') ) {
        clientX = dx.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        clientY = dx.changedTouches[0].clientY;
        dx = clientX - this.data('ox');
        dy = clientY - this.data('oy');
    }
    this.attr({
                transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
            });
} 

var start = function( x, y, ev) {
    if( (typeof x == 'object') && ( x.type == 'touchstart') ) {
        x.preventDefault();
        this.data('ox', x.changedTouches[0].clientX );
        this.data('oy', x.changedTouches[0].clientY );  
    }
    this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local );
}

var stop = function() {
}

rect.touchstart( start );
rect.touchmove( move );
rect.touchend( stop );

circle.drag(move, start, stop )
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM4L9/7/)

Comment: A quick test with Chrome it and it seems to work well.

Comment: Just noticed that touch drag and drop works on the rectangle and the circle.  I changed the rect touch lines to just this: rect.drag(move, start, stop ) and both the rect and circle now work with mouse and touch.

Comment: I suspect if this works with the drag() function, that your device isn't actually using touchevents and you're using standard mouseevents.

Comment: The code as shown doesn't handle the drop; if you get that to work, I'd love to see it (This helped me with drag, but I'm struggling with drop!)